# Quota increase on Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, quota

Well I got my account with 72 CPU's  us-central1  but I need to use 96vCPU so I go to increase my quotas but It says that I need to wait around 48 hours, I create the Project Thursday 12/03/2020 around 2:30PM  today is Monday 11:AM and it's been more than 48 hours , I asked again for quota increase , cause the last one I tried was on Sunday.
It said again that I don't have enough "bill history" or wait 48 hours

-Bill History : I have like 5 projects paying  but I create another 5 to made some ML test and now they said I don't have enough "bill history"

-48 hours: I don't think that 48 hours are just 48 hours , I think that are more than just 48

So after explain it , I wanna know how much real time I need to wait to increase my quotas ? I don't know what to do , already use chat assistant and don't get an according good answer ..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a vendor support question. We cannot answer how long it takes for a vendor to approve your account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you submitted a Quota Request you should have received an email with a subject similar to **"[#xxxx] Quota Increase Request For ..."** If you have any questions regarding the process please respond to that email as it will automatically created a case with Google Cloud Support where  representative will be able to respond to your question.

> So after explain it , I wanna know how much real time I need to wait
>   to increase my quotas ?

It depends on your billing account history the response takes longer is the billing account is brand new.

> Already use chat assistant and don't get an according good answer

Chat representatives can help you with technical product issues, the quota team is different and there is no real time support with them. The only way to communicate with the quota team is by responding to the email I previously mentioned

Please remember that **StackOverflow community is not a support site for your favorite provider** you risk to get your questions removed from the community.